# Jetty: HelloWorld example cannot change content

Tags: java, jetty

I'm new to Jetty, and I tried to run the example for "HelloWorld"

```
public class HelloWorld extends AbstractHandler
{
    public void handle(String target,
                       Request baseRequest,
                       HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(new HelloWorld());

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

and the "Hello World" does shows on the JSP page in my localhost:8080. But I'm not able to change any content inside, or even stop the server. What can I do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. Cuz I run it in my eclipse, so I need to stop the server that created from eclipse, and the only way to kill the server is go to the tast manager, and end all the java program. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you do a join() at the end, your only way to stop the server is to kill it.
If you haven't succeed in stopping your server, how can you say that you cannot change the content?

Comment: java -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=secret -jar start.jar - –stopt

Comment: This the command I use to stop my server, is that correct? but since I have a pluggin in my exlipse and I also use the cmd, how to make sure that both of them are stop working?!